# Is there a way to tell in-game if a Pokemon can evolve other than when it is first registered?

Tags: pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon

Whenever a Pokemon is first registered upon initial capture, the registered screen shows poke balls in the background indicating if the Pokemon can evolve. However there does not seem to be any way after that to determine if it can evolve. I have Pokemon I captured early on in my playthrough and I can't remember if they can evolve or not. Is there some indicator I'm missing in the Pokedex, or does this information become available later (I just reached the 2nd island, so perhaps I haven't unlocked that feature yet).

Comment: I know that at least in other games, as you collect Pokemon you'll see in your Pokedex (when sorted by number) that it will jump in viewed Pokemon. Like, your Pokedex might go "#1 Rowlet, #2 Dartrix, #3 ???, #4 Litten" and there's usually pretty good odds that as your Pokedex gets fuller that those holes will be filled in by a Pokemon evolving as evolution chains are usually listed in order.  -  As for a direct indicator, I haven't played S/M or US/UM so I can't say for certain there.

Comment: If the post actually answered your question, please accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see that screen once you have access to the *Alola Pokedex*, the lower screen lists every Pokemon encountered, while in the upper screen you have this view:

[image]
<sub>[Incomplete page]</sub>

[image]
<sub>[Complete page]</sub>

which is the same "screen with pokeballs in the background indicating if the Pokemon can evolve" you were talking about.

I've played only 3 hours on my Ultra Moon copy, and I already have that. But I've redeemed some gift Pokemon like shiny Solgaleo, so my Pokedex may be "biased".